# Нужна ли запятая?

Tags: пунктуация

"Самое страшное, что ты ждешь (,) сам не зная чего".
Конечно, деепричастный оборот выделяется запятыми, но, может, это некое неразложимое сочетание?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Думаю, что "**сам не зная чего**" - это устойчивое сочетание разговорного типа. Точнее, наверное, было бы САМ НЕ ЗНАЕШЬ ЧЕГО. Ср.: ***Сам не знаю чем*** - *не то едой, не то духами, - не разобрать, но сразу чувствуешь, что ты дома*. (Джером Сэлинджер. "Над пропастью во ржи").
 В Вашем предложении устойчивое выражение "**сам не зная чего**" является ***дополнением***. Ср.: "Самое страшное, что ты **ждешь (чего?)** чего-то неопределённого (= сам не зная чего)".  Запятую ставить не следует: ***"Самое страшное, что ты ждешь сам не зная чего"***

Answer (score 0):

К сожалению, полного списка устойчивых сочетаний нет. Порассуждаем.  Это сочетание очень похоже на устойчивое. Ждешь сам не зная чего - Ждешь неизвестное, непонятное.  Но если Вы делаете смысловой акцент на "не знаешь" - *ждешь и **не знаеш**ь чего*, тогда это деепричастие и запятая нужна.